# Why has my consecutive-days count reset on SO?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, consecutive-days

I'm not entirely sure why, but my consecutive-days count has reset to 1 on Stack Overflow, when it absolutely definitely shouldn't have. I'll shamelessly admit to trying to get the badges for it, and it's a bit annoying to start from 1 when I was on 26/27. I know SO runs off GMT+8 or something like that, but I've logged on once, then 22 hours later, then 12 hours later, which should cover all possible combinations for the time zones.

I've logged in on:

- Friday, ~4pm GMT (finished work at 4.15 and checked shortly before that)
- Saturday, 2.15pm GMT (logged in just before I headed out to play a gig)
- Now, Sunday at 2:00am GMT (just got back in from said gig)

Has anything happened recently to cause this?

Edit: I'm off to bed now, I'm knackered :P I'll check back in the morning for answers :)

Update: Yes, I did more than just visit the homepage each time - I've seen a couple of meta threads about that happening to other people, so I open a question, click "Post Answer" (but don't write one, or post it) and view someone's profile each time.

Comment: What did you do on Saturday at 2:15 pm? Did you navigate anywhere at all or just log in?

Comment: sometimes you have to do more than just log in, view a few pages or something...

Comment: Edited post - yes, every time :) I'm already aware of that gotcha, I was making sure that didn't happen

Comment: So, you create a dummy question and begin the process of creating an answer, just to get a badge? I can't see those questions in your profile so I assume you've been deleting them also? If so, I wouldn't recommend it because it's easy to get question-banned if you keep deleting your own questions. Much better to actually interact with the site normally.

Comment: @RivieraKid I think you've got the wrong end of the stick; re-read the post properly because I can't see how you read it to mean that

Comment: Aaah, sorry - when you said you opened questions, I took that to mean you created new ones, which of course, would be bad (TM). My bad.

Answer (score 18):

I see you visited the site on:

- 2012-03-02 21:28:20.190
- 2012-03-04 01:51:42.787

...but no visits inbetween those dates from your Account ID or any of your IPs used on 3-02 or 3-04.  So you reset because you didn't visit the site on 3-03.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to this, been pretty busy since I posted the question. I've definitely visited the site between those two timestamps, is there any reason why it wouldn't "see" me? I'm getting a little confused now

Comment: @Joe - nope, we log literally *every* hit to our network.

Comment: @NickCraver I really doubt when you say that you log literally _every_ hit on your network. Many people are facing this buggy behavior. I can say I visit SO everyday (in weekdays almost after every hour or so and on weekend at least twice). And I'm pretty **sure** about it. I log into SO from work/home (different) machines. The ISP at both place is also same. Not sure why SO reset my visit counter to 1. The details showed that I didn't visit SO for a complete day which is **not** true and is frustrating. (note - If not possible to check SO from desktop/laptop I visit from mobile.)

Comment: @Bongs - we quite literally log *every* request to our network, I have a 10 TB database to prove it.  You didn't visit the site logged in yesterday.  Keep in mind three things: you have to be logged in, and **the home page does not count** (this has *always* been the case), and our day is UTC midnight to midnight, you must visit something besides the homepage each UTC day to be continuous (again, this has *always* been the case).

Comment: @NickCraver I just faced this issued, about an hour, or so, ago I had a hit consecutive day count of 86. And now its off to 1. Could you explain that please?